# Quickest way to get the position of the leading 1 in a bitset for an integer?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, bit-manipulation, c99

Consider this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
typedef uint8_t Tnum;
template <typename T>
void printBits(T a)
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<(sizeof(a) * 8)>(a).to_string() << '\n';
}
int main()
{
    printBits(Tnum(15));
    printBits(Tnum(17));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

it prints

```
00001111
00010001
```

Now consider this 2 guys from the previous output

```
00001111
    ^
00010001
   ^
```

I would like to know how, given a signed or unsigned integer type, and given a value for an instance of that type, I can get the location of that leading `1` in the pattern, starting to count from `0` the result I expect is `3` for the first row, `4` for the second one. The total amount of positions involved is also acceptable to me, like `4` for the first row and `5` for the second one.

I don't have Hacker's Delight or similar text available at the moment and I can't find any quick bit twiddling .

[This](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) is kinda it but it's error prone and it will never pass a conversion test or set of warning flags about conversions, at least in my case. Plus it's probably a non-optimal choice.

Please no lookup tables, I'm willing to accept anything that doesn't cause conversion issues and doesn't use a LUT. For C89/99 and C++11 .

Answer (score 4):

If this is X86 and you can use assembly, there's the bit scan reverse instruction. Depending on the compiler, there may be an intrinsic for this.

[bit scan reverse](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_20.html)

Comment: On GCC it's called `__builtin_clz`.

Comment: this sounds really interesting, the problem is that it will probably work based on the size of the native word for the CPU, for example it will probably expect a 32 bit wide integer on most if not all the x86 cpus, that's a waste/problem when you have, let's say, an 8 bit wide unsigned integer or just an integer that is not as large as the native word.

Comment: @user2485710 A shorter integer has to be promoted to a word in order to be pushed onto the stack or passed in a register anyway.

Comment: @user2485710: The BSR instruction has 16-, 32-, and 64-bit variants.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have access to hacker's delight ? Proxy limitation ?

Here is the solution from http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/nlz.c.txt

```
int nlz1(unsigned x) {
   int n;

   if (x == 0) return(32);
   n = 0;
   if (x <= 0x0000FFFF) {n = n +16; x = x <<16;}
   if (x <= 0x00FFFFFF) {n = n + 8; x = x << 8;}
   if (x <= 0x0FFFFFFF) {n = n + 4; x = x << 4;}
   if (x <= 0x3FFFFFFF) {n = n + 2; x = x << 2;}
   if (x <= 0x7FFFFFFF) {n = n + 1;}
   return n;
}
```

Comment: this is basically the same as the other one on the other bit-twiddling site, and it looks so branchy and non-optimal; By the way I didn't knew about the online stuff on the website, thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, x86-64 processors have the most significant bit (MSB) instruction which can be accessed through compilers using either inline assembly or compiler instructions (*intrinsics*). The Microsoft C compiler has the *_BitScanReverse* instruction for 32bits.

An example of how to insert inline assembly code for the gcc compiler may be found here: https://www.biicode.com/pablodev/pablodev/bitscan/master/25/bitboard.h

In case you are not interested in this type of solutions an O(log(N)) solution with a good compromise between table size and speed using a de Bruijn magic number is:

```
uint32_t v;
int r;
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1;  
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Basically the first shifts round the input number to one less than a power of 2 and then de Bruijn multiplication and lookup does the rest. The shifts are not necessary when it is known that the input number is a power of 2 (the magic number is different though). All information is available [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*BitScanRevers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd.aspx) intrinsic if you're using visual studio.